# Definite integral $\int _{0}^{1}\sqrt [3] {2x^{3}-3x^{2}-x+1}~\mathrm dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral
>   $$\int _{0}^{1}\sqrt [3] {2x^{3}-3x^{2}-x+1}~\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Is it 0? This is based on a very crude guess.

Comment: I doubt that this can be expressed in terms of simple constants: Mathematica 7 gives a very ugly result in terms of the Appell hypergeometric function $F_1$.

Comment: We seperated lines from 0 to (1/2) and from (1/2) to 1 ,because at (1/2) point second derivative is 0

Comment: i have got a complex value of this integral

Comment: Substitute $u=x +1/2$ to see that this function is odd hence the integral equals zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note firstly that:

$(2x^{3} -3x^{2}-x+1)^{1/3} =[(2(x-\frac{1}{2})((x-\frac{1}{2})^{2} -\frac{5}{4})]^{1/3}$

Thus let $u=x-\frac{1}{2}$.

The upper limit becomes $\frac{1}{2} $ and the lower limit becomes $\frac{-1}{2}$.

And so we have:

$\int^{1/2}_{-1/2} (2u^{3} -\frac{5u}{2}) du$

Note that the expression inside the integral is odd and passes through the origin, and since the integral is the sum of the signed areas bounded by the curve and the $x$ axis, the sum of these areas must be $0$. Consequently the integral is $0$.